# maven dependency exists but classDefNotFound?

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, wadl

I have the following dependency in my pom file:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.ws.wadl</groupId>
    <artifactId>wadl-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

the jar file exists on the system and the dependency can be resolved. but when the code is run it fails on java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.ws.wadl.util.DSDispatcher.  DSDispatcher exists in the jar file and in the correct package. Can anyone suggest what the issue might be? I've tried adding all the dependencies from wadl-core pom to my pom, that has not helped and i've tried the various scopes on my dependency.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your application? Is wadl-core present in the classpath at runtime (so not only in maven repo)?

Comment: Hi Damien, I have not checked this.. the application is run in JBoss (5.1) currently I am testing using a SOAP tool (there are two web services involved - I make a call to one, which performs some actions and then kicks off a procedure to call this external wadl....)  how can I check the classpath at runtime?

Comment: Thanks!! I added the jar to the jboss lib and it resolved the error, so looks as though you are correct - classpath issue!

Answer (score 0):

According to your answers in the comments, it seems you're project is packaged into a war file (or ear). Rather than putting wadl-core in JBoss lib, it should really be embedded into your archive.

If you use `<packaging>war</packaging>` into the pom.xml of your application along with the declaration of dependency mentioned in your question, wadl-core should be present into WEB-INF/lib in your war file.